# Can't get text on same line as counter using <div></div>

Tags: html

Using the HTML code below:

```
<font face="verdana" size="3" color="#666666"><div id="result"  &nbsp;&nbsp; Downloads></div></font>
```

I can get the number of downloads to show from the counter, i.e., "result", but can't get the word "Download" to follow on the same line.  If I place the `</div>` after the counter, then "Download" shows on the next line.  Somehow, `</div>` seems like a `<br>` command?

When done, the goal is to show the following:

36 Downloads

Comment: Shouldn't it be <div id="result">Downloads</div> ?

Comment: Your html is incorrect, the `<div ... >` cannot contain random text inside the tag.

Comment: actually, it does... Because `<div>` is a block-level element. Oh, and `<font>` is dead, use css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the "result" element that will contain the number from the word "Downloads". Also I switched to using a `<span>` because by default it goes on the same line as what follows after it.

Example:

```js
document.getElementById("result").innerText = "12345";
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="result"></span> Downloads
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice, and condensed code, worked like a charm!  Will definitely go with this as the answer.

Comment: FYI-firefox on an android device can't see the counter value, but can see the "Download" string.  Any suggestions? Is the GetElementByID() css or java script?

Comment: Works here using the  above snippet, also for FF on Android, although I have to tell it to use 'Desktop Website' mode (probably a Stack Overflow quirk/limitation)

Comment: Using an html code block on the page, the following function call before the display does not seem to work:  `'<script>
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  localStorage.clickcount ;
</script>

<font face="arial" size="3" color="black"><div>
  <span id="result"></span> Downloads
</div></font>`

Comment: You may need to wait until the **`result`** element actually exists. As written, the piece of JS may run too soon, i.e. before the element has been created. If you put the script *after* the HTML it may work already. Or see other more general strategies to avoid running script too early, e.g. jQuery -> `$(document).ready(function() { /* Your code here */ });` and even then that code has to be put after the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

div tags are set to have display: block; in CSS, if you want two divs to appear side by side you need to either change to display: inline-block; or use float or flexbox properties.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't closed the div correctly, can you try this?

`<font face="verdana" size="3" color="#666666"><div id="result">&nbsp;&nbsp; Downloads</div></font>`

Answer (score 0):

Downloads is in a wrong position. This how it should be:

```
 <font face="verdana" size="3" color="#666666"><div id="result">&nbsp;&nbsp; Downloads</div></font>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments, answers.  I pasted all of them and they had varying behavior after clicking the counter and reloading the page.  I was able to get the desired results using:

```
<font face="verdana" size="3" color="#666666"><span id="result"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Downloads</font>
```